# regex avoid replace number from (.*) replacement

Tags: regex, replace, match

I want to remove part of string using start and end words in string. At the same i want to keep number appear in this range.

String:

```
<FORMAT=T>8</FORMAT><FORMAT=ty>45</FORMAT>
```

Regex:

```
/(<FORMAT=T>).[^<FORMAT]*(<\/FORMAT>)/gm
```

output

```
<FORMAT=ty>45</FORMAT>
```

Expected output: I want keep number appear in between `<FORMAT=T>...</FORMAT>`

> 8<FORMAT=ty>45</FORMAT>

Comment: It looks like you want _substitution_. Match: `<FORMAT=T>(\d+)</FORMAT>` Substitute with `\1`. [example](https://regex101.com/r/lLwFL1/1)

Comment: no need `[^<FORMAT]`?

Comment: If you can reach the site where I posted an example, you can try it out with more example strings to see if it works. If it doesn't work you could update your question with more info about why it doesn't.

Comment: That example works, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want *substitution* (search/replace):

- Match: `<FORMAT=T>(\d+)</FORMAT>` where the number between the tags is captured. `\d` may need to be `[0-9]` in some [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) engines.
- Substitute with `\1` or `$1` depending on your [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) engine.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lLwFL1/1)

Answer (score 0):

It'd be helpful to know what regex engine you're running as they're all a little different, but I'll take a stab and hope the syntax is correct.  You should update your question to provide the particular engine you're running.

```
/<FORMAT=T>(\d+)<\/FORMAT>(<FORMAT=ty>\d+<\/FORMAT>)/\1\2/gm
```

you might want to review the global and multiline modifiers too, I suspect they aren't necessary, but can't say for sure without more of the context.